# Return the string in Trie

Tags: python, trie

I have this  Trie:

```
                a
               / \
              b   c
             / \   \
            t   y   u
           2     5   3
numbers at leaf stands for frequency, stored at the terminal node
```

and I have default Trie search function to search for a string. When I do `search('a')`, it'll return `aby` since it is the most frequently inserted string. Frequency is stored by `self.count` in my function.
I'd prefer not to post my code.

How would you approach solving and returning the nodes from `a` to `y`?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Id create an element in the every node ot trie that indicates the child with the maximum frequence path. And then do a depth first search based on this index.

Comment: @AlbinPaul every node (letter) is represented by node.tree[index], where index is the ord of the letter. How should I do a dfs based on this? I am not using and won't be using any dictionaries/sets.

Comment: well, find a mechanism for every node to point to the next node that it needs to traverse to. Cant say much without seeing what code you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function to traverse the trie and produce all strings that include the search value as a substring:

Simple trie setup:

```
class Trie:
   def __init__(self, l=None):
      self.l, self.count, self.tree = l, 0, []
   def insert_l(self, word):
      if word:
         if not (n:=[i for i in self.tree if i.l == word[0]]):
            self.tree.append(Trie(word[0]))
            self.tree[-1].add_word(word)
         else:
            n[-1].add_word(word)
   def add_word(self, word):
      if self.l is not None:
         self.count += 1
      self.insert_l(word if self.l is None else word[1:])
```

---

Now, a `search` method can be added to `Trie`:

```
class Trie:
    ...
    def search(self, word):
      def _search(t, c = []):
         if not t.tree:
            yield c+[t]
         else:
            for i in t.tree:
              yield from _search(i, c if t.l is None else c+[t])
      if (l:=[(j, i) for i in _search(self) if word in (j:=''.join(k.l for k in i))]):
         return max(l, key=lambda x:x[-1][-1].count)[0]

t = Trie()
words = ['abt', 'abt', 'aby', 'aby', 'aby', 'aby', 'aby', 'acu', 'acu', 'acu']
for word in words:
   t.add_word(word)

print(t.search('a'))
```

Output:

```
'aby'
```